# Higher API levels couldn’t find drawable folder

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

I’m just playing with android studio. I’ve made a small app with some gifs (located at drawable folder) and a theme (with his windowBackground in drawable’s). In the preview it all works fine. And also if I install it on my phone (android 4.4) but once I install it on q higher level android all images and the theme cann’t be found. It gives me a not found exception. I’ve also take a look if I had multiple drawable folders. But I just have 1; drawable. How to fix this? Thanks

Res folder:

[image: folder res]

Styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="SplashScreen" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/loading</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

one part of GifView:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button28"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button27"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65"
        android:src="@drawable/lion" />
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword 'Smaobm29'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/ruben/Desktop/Programmeren/key0.jks')
            storePassword 'Smaobm29'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.game_force.ruben.jelle_app"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.2'
}
```

and what's inside drawable folder:

[image: drawable files]

Comment: Please, publish an exception stack trace

Comment: It says resouces$notfoundexception:drawable/loading. And also all images/gifs from drawable folder aren’t showinh

Comment: I’ve found out that it only happens if android 8+ is installed